# angular 2 array list undefined

Tags: arrays, angular

this is (data)
[image]

this is (data[0]) [image]

here is my html

```
<div  class="page">
<paper-card heading="Login Form">
  <div class="card-content">
    <paper-input [(ngModel)]="user.username" label="Username"></paper-input>
    <paper-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" label="Password" type="password"></paper-input>
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions" align="end">
    <paper-button class="login" id="Login" raised disabled (click)="Login(user)">Login</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>
</div>

<paper-dialog id="wrong" modal>
  <p>Your username or password wrong please check again.</p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Ok..</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

here is my full code, when im trying to get array from http res its show undefined

```
Login(user){
        this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://localhost:5000/user','POST',{username:user.username, password:user.password},null).subscribe((data)=>{ 
                if (data.length > 0 ){
                    this._userdetails.setDetails(data);
                    this._router.navigate(['MainMenu']);
                    console.log(data.name); <<<<<<< here is the part
                }else {
                    var wmodal :any = document.getElementById('wrong');
                    wmodal.open();
                }

            });
        }
```

but if im doing the `console.log(data);`
it shows the result

```
Array[1]
0
:
Object
Name
:
"Admin"
Password
:
"Admin"
SBU
:
"IT"
Updateon
:
"2016-12-21T17:50:21.393Z"
UserName
:
"Admin"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]
```

here is the array i get from http req

```
[{"UserName":"Admin","Password":"Admin","Name":"Admin","SBU":"IT","Updateon":"2016-12-21T17:50:21.393Z"}]
```

what i want to get is the name = admin

so thats why im doing `console.log(data.name)`

Comment: How do you call `test` method? Please add more code

Comment: @yurzui here is my button code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer after OP edited the post

If `data` is an array first you need to select the correct element.

Like

```
Login(user){
        this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://localhost:5000/user','POST',{username:user.username, password:user.password},null).subscribe((data)=>{ 
                if (data.length > 0 ){
                    this._userdetails.setDetails(data);
                    this._router.navigate(['MainMenu']);
                    console.log(data[0].Name); //<<<<<<< Assuming your data is correct
                }else {
                    var wmodal :any = document.getElementById('wrong');
                    wmodal.open();
                }
        });
}
```

**old answer**

You are trying to access a local variable with `this` in this code.

```
test(){
  var b = []
  b = this.a; //<-- add this
  console.log(b.Name); //<-- remove this
}
```

Also `a` is an object in your field then you assign it to an empty array inside test.

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ekmcCaiszsPoM1gV6NRQ?p=preview

Comment: yeah know its working if like that, but mine still doesnot work, maybe because its from http req and res please check my code again thanks

Comment: @Rommy your question doesn't include the relationship between `Login()` and the variables which you try to display. Can you add it?

Comment: @Rommy you've changed the question completely.. And I still can't see what is undefined as a variable..

Comment: well im sorry, i make it simple before so that every one can understand now its complicated, "data" is my array that i got from http request, but when im doing consolel.log(data.name) its show undefined , still not got it?

Comment: @Rommy Where are you doing the `console.log(data.name)`? Inside the subscribe, if `data` has a `name` field it **will** be defined.  So show us where it is undefined in your code, got it?

Comment: yessss, thats the point, im doing the console.log inside the subscribe and my array has a name field but still not defined

Comment: @Rommy see my updated answer. Your data is not an object but you are trying to select it as one.

Comment: yes i try that 1 already also, with data[0].name but still undefined , im sorry  for before im not try to mock you no offence tho

Comment: @Rommy console.log it step by step. First the data then data[0] what does it log?

Comment: @Rommy where is data[0] ?

Comment: @Rommy you are logging `data[0].Name` right? not `data[0].name`.

Comment: oh my god, the capital change everything, how stupid i am , thank's its working